# Java correct way to compare a long value

Tags: java

Is this the correct way to compare a long value ?

```
user.getUserId() == 3
```

or

```
user.getUserId() == 3L


getUserId().equals(3L)
Error cannot invoke long on primitive type long
```

I have the following code where we compare the UserID is equals to 3

JavaMB.java

```
if (user.getUserId() == 3) {
   this.setName(true); 
   } else {
   this.setName(false);
}
```

Entity.java

```
private long userId;
private string name;
```

DB

```
Number VARCHAR2
ID  Name
3   Maek
7   Rick
8   Wquar
```

Comment: Both are correct (as long as the value is in `int` range. Once your constant exceeds the range of an `int` - `L`, or `l`, is required.

Comment: On a separate note, you can replace your whole if-else with `this.setName(user.getUserId() == 3);`

Comment: Tried both ways don't work, No error in console, Some how it does not compare or  equals to 3 , The user ID is a long value we are comparing that with a long value 3

Comment: You've shown us `private long userId;`, but you have not shown us what `getUserId()` returns.  Remember that instances of class `Integer` are not the same (ie, do not compare with ==) as instances of `Long`.

Comment: Your `Entity.java` is not accurate; it uses `string`, which is not correct. The behavior of `long` and `Long` is not identical, and database entities usually have a nullable type for the ID.

Comment: The easiest and most helpful way to find out 'the correct way' is to try for yourself and see if and how it works.

Comment: @racraman a long value

Comment: @pasha Im guessing it doesn’t - instead I think it would be returning a Long value (ie returns an object, not the primitive value).  As I mentioned, that would cause problems since Java would only autobox 3 to an Integer, not to a Long.  Can you edit the question to include that getUserId() method to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

All the ways you have mentioned are correct. Check the following code and its output:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Long l1 = 3L;
        System.out.println(l1.equals(3L));
        System.out.println(l1 == 3);

        long l2 = 3;
        System.out.println(l2 == 3L);
        System.out.println(Long.valueOf(3L).equals(l2));

        System.out.println(l1.equals(l2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
true
```